# Numpy find index in a list of arrays appeared in another list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So suppose I have a list of arrays called `original_arr`, another list of arrays called `find_arr`,how can I find the index of elements of `original_arr` appeared in `find_arr`? (I have many number of lists to deal with)

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(9,3)
original_arr = np.split(a,3)
>>> original_arr
>>> [array([[0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8]]), 
     array([[ 9, 10, 11],
            [12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17]]), 
     array([[18, 19, 20],
            [21, 22, 23],
            [24, 25, 26]])]

b = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[12,13,14],[15,16,17],[21,22,23]])
find_arr =  np.split(b,np.array([2,2,1]).cumsum()[:-1])
>>> find_arr
>>> [array([[0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5]]), 
     array([[12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17]]), 
     array([[21, 22, 23]])]
```

so I tried the code below, but it doesn't work

```
index = np.empty((0,2),int)

for i in range (len(find_arr)):
    for j in range (len(find_arr[i])):
        m = np.where((original_arr[i] == find_arr[i][j]).all(axis=1))
        index = np.append(index,m,axis=0)
```

what I expect the output is to be (for example. because `[0, 1, 2]` in `find_arr` appears in `original_arr[0][0]`, so the output should be `[0,0]` or `[[0],[0]]`) :

```
array[[[0,0],[0,1]],
      [[1,1],[1,2]],
      [[2,1]]]

or 
array[[[[0],[0]],[[0],[1]]],
      [[[1],[1]],[[1],[2]]],
      [[[2],[1]]]]
```

can anybody check where my code is wrong? or is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append the row number, `i`, to `m`, but `m` has different type. So take the output from `np.where(..)[0][0]` as below and append it to `i` before inserting into `index`.

```
for i in range (len(find_arr)):
    for j in range (len(find_arr[i])):
        m = np.where((original_arr[i] == find_arr[i][j]))[0][0]
        index = np.append(index,[[i, m]],axis=0)
```

Another option, which might be a bit faster, is to use `np.nonzero(..==..)[0][0]` like this:

```
m = np.nonzero((original_arr[i] == find_arr[i][j]))[0][0]
```

Both of which will output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 1]]
```

as you would expect.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. but I want to ask is there any way that the output are already divided and has the length `3` , like  `[[[0 0] [0 1]], [[1 1],[1 2]], [[2 1]]]`

Comment: @BAOLIAN, you can get this format but it will be much easier to use normal lists in this case like this: `index = []
for i in range(len(find_arr)):
    ind = []
    for j in range(len(find_arr[i])):
        for J in range(len(original_arr[i])):
            if all(original_arr[i][J] == find_arr[i][j]):
                ind.append([i,J])
    index.append(ind)`